# Why is array not printing?

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I know its something simple but I cant figure out why my array is not printing once the user enters the size and integers. I finally was able to get the user to determine the size of the array and enter their own integers but now the program returns right after.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //Declare a size variable
    int size = 0;
    
    //Ask user how many numbers are in list:
    printf("How many integers?");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    printf("Please enter integers:");
    int arr[size];
    scanf("%d", arr);
    
    //Calculate length of array
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    //Test print to see if array is returning the right amount of integers.
    //printf("%d", length);
    
    //Print original array
    for(int i = 0; i > length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i > length` -> `i < length`. BTW, you don't really need `length`. Just use `size`;

Comment: `scanf("%d", arr);` that also needs to go into a loop. Similar to what you did for the `printf` loop. `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", arr);
```

Because `arr` now is a pointer to `arr[0]`, `scanf("%d", arr);` will just input the first element of the array.

You have to put it in a `for` loop:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}
```

This `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i > length; i++)
{
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
}
```

will never executed, because `length` is always larger than `0`, so when `i = 0`, `i > length` is `false`.

You should use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
}
```

Also, `length` is just `size`, so you don't need `length`

So your code should be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    
    printf("How many integers?");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    printf("Please enter integers:");
    int arr[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }    

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just ran the code and it prints out what might be memory numbers instead of the integers the user enters. Any ideas?

Comment: @NickyReds works fine for me. What's your input?

Comment: It was operator error on my behalf. Thank you!